# AWS Quickstart Onica Camera Connector guide : failed to create CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am trying to use AWS [quickstart-onica-connected-camera](https://github.com/DalavanCloud/quickstart-onica-connected-camera) guide in order to stream camera videos to AWS Kinesis, but while creating stack using cloudformation template ,it leads to following error:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [ProvisioningKeyFunction, ExampleCameraStatusLambda, RoleAliasFunction, MonitoringLambdaFunction, CameraShadowLambda, ExampleCameraPairingLambda, StackAvailabilityFunction].
```

Link to Quickstart guide: https://github.com/DalavanCloud/quickstart-onica-connected-camera

Comment: Are there any other error messages?  Please add them to the post.

Comment: This is the only error message I am getting right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with NodeJS deprecated version being used in the template for executing Lambda Functions, changing that to latest supported version worked.